# Sum of representations of associative algebras

Tags: representation-theory, lie-algebras

It is well known that if $L$ is a Lie algebra and $\rho, \mu: L \to \mathrm{End}^{(-)}(V)$ are its representations then if $[\rho(x),\mu(y)]=0$ for all $x,y\in L$, then $\rho+\mu$ is a new representions of $L$. In particular we get that for two $L$-modules $M_1,M_2$, the set $M_1\otimes M_2$ is a $L$-module where $(a\otimes b) \cdot x:= a\cdot x \otimes b + a \otimes b\cdot x$.

Assume now that we have an associative algebra $A$ and two representations $\rho, \mu: A \to \mathrm{End}(V)$. Suppose that $\rho(x)\mu(y) + \mu(x)\rho(y) = 0$ for all $x,y\in A$. Then $\rho+\mu$ is a new representation of $A$. And then, if the $A$ is considered over a field of characteristic $2$ and let $M_1$, $M_2$ be left and right $A$-modules, respectively. Then $M_1\otimes M_2$ is an $A$-bimodule with the same action as in Lie case. Is this correct? N. Jacobson in his book ``Lie Algebras'' (I.6) wrote *Nothing like this (as in Lie case) holds in the associative case*.

Comment: Just checking: You really want characteristic $2$, and no other characteristic? And, at the end you say it's an $A$-*bi*module, as opposed to just a module in the Lie algebra case.

Comment: I meant that for the Lie case (if the field has characterisit 2) the condition $[\rho(x),\mu(y)]=0$ is $\rho(x)\mu(y) + \mu(x)\rho(y)=0$. Thus if we want a map $\rho+\mu$ to be a representation for an associative algebra we then get exactly the seame condition as before. And I cannot understand what N. Jacobson meant (nothing like this holds in the associative case).

Comment: Hmm ... how is $\mu + \rho$ under the stated condition a new representation of $A$? E.g.  as soon as $A$ is unital, and both $\mu$ and $\rho$ map $1_A$ to $id$, the map $\mu+\rho$ will not do that.

Comment: You are right, but let us assume that A has no unit. We then get $(\rho+\mu)(xy) = \rho(x)\rho(y) + \mu(x)\mu(y)$ and $\bigl((\rho + \mu)(x)\bigr) \cdot \bigl ( (\rho+\mu)(y)\bigl) =  (\rho(x) + \mu(x))\cdot(\rho(y)+\mu(y)) = \rho(x)\rho(y) + \rho(x)\mu(y) + \mu(x)\rho(y) + \mu(x)\mu(y) = \rho(x)\rho(y) + \mu(x)\mu(y)$ becase of $\rho(x)\mu(y) + \mu(x)\rho(y)$ has been assumted to be zero. Hence, $\rho+\mu$ is a new representation of $A$ which does not contane $1_A$.

Comment: So what you are saying is that if $A$ is non-unital **and** of characteristic $2$ (and I, for one, do not know enough about non-unital algebras to decide if "characteristic" even works as usual there), then there might be something analogous to the Lie case. Since anyway this seems to be a very special case, maybe Jacobson's statement should be interpreted with an "In general," in front of it? --- Besides, I still have not seen how the issue of module versus bimodule is clarified?